# How to combine multiple imported targets into one

Tags: cmake

Having been unable to find an answer to this question, I decided to post it here.
I'm trying to setup a small cmake-based build and am not sure how should I tackle it.
I realize the question addresses a "how" and not a "what" but I am open for any alternative solution that doesn't feel like a hack.

I need to add a post build command to copy some (imported) dlls to my target's output:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
            $<TARGET_FILE:MyImportedDlls::All>
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>
)
```

I made a "find" script for the imported dlls that creates one target for each dll

```
set(LIB_FILES
    "${PATH_TO_LIBS}/lib1.dll"
    "${PATH_TO_LIBS}/lib2.dll"
    "${PATH_TO_LIBS}/lib3.dll"
)

unset(TARGETS)
foreach(LIB_FILE ${LIB_FILES})
    get_filename_component(FN ${LIB_FILE} NAME_WE)
    add_library(MyImportedDlls::${FN} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(MyImportedDlls::${FN} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIB_FILE}")
    list(APPEND TARGETS "MyImportedDlls::${FN}")
endforeach()
```

My problem is: how to create a "combined" target that I can use in my custom command?

Answer (score 0):

Just have 3 post build commands, one for each target.

```
foreach(target IN LISTS TARGETS)
    add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        $<TARGET_FILE:${target}>
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>
     ) 
endforeach()
```

Comment: Alternatively I could just export the LIB_FILES and use that in the custom command. But that is exactly what I want to avoid: having insight into how the MyImportedDlls is made up and knowing a "magic" variable name outside the cmake module that builds it. Ideally I'd like to communicate (between modules) exclusively through targets and their properties.